# Copying GUI TextBox data to a text file

Tags: powershell

I know this a simple solution but I can not figure out the syntax.  I'm trying to take information from a multi-line TextBox and place it in a file when a button click happens.
Here is where I'm at currently as an incomplete idea of where I'm going with it.  The problem is I want to take a list of Machines from a GUI text box and place it into a text file.

```
$button.add_button(
    Get-Content $AddButton.TEXT | Foreach-Object {" I want to pipe into a c:\temp\PROD\Machines.txt"})
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Really not sure were I should start... ;)

- I guess method is `Add_Click`
- if `$AddButon` is your TextBox - you can access property directly rather than use `Get-Content` cmdlet
- I would just use `Out-File`

Code:

```
$button.Add_Click({
    $AddButton.Text | Out-File c:\temp\PROD\Machines.txt
})
```

Not tested.

Comment: Actually this makes total sense of what I'm trying to do.  I was missing the "Out-File"...  That so much...

Comment: Also I had a mis-type on that function name..lol  Thanks again.